# A question about a scene in Dumb and Dumber To

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, dumb-and-dumber-to

There is a scene where Harry and Lloyd talk:

> Harry Dunne: How many days are in April?
>
> Lloyd Christmas: 30 days have September, all the rest I can't remember.
>
> Harry Dunne: Must be 31 because nothing rhymes with August.
>
> Lloyd Christmas: Nah, I think it's 32, Harry. April's a leap month.

What's Harry talking about when he said "Nothing rhymes with August"? And what's a leap month? And what is Harry mention August for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *must* remember that they're both idiots. ;)

Harry is talking about [this rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_days_hath_September) that helps you remember how many days are in each month and completely misses its point.

And Lloyd is just confused about the concept of [leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) and thinks April always has an extra day. (Of course, there technically *are* leap months - see [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/chinese-leap-year.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_months) - but that's not what he means).

Comment: Thanks, I know they are idiots and sometimes I am confused about what they've said . And what is Harry mention August for ?

Comment: For no reason, I think it's just an example of how surreal his stupidity is. He's rearranging that old rhyme in his mind and grouping months together in made-up and arbitrary ways.